# Firebase Query get values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of Child-Data and wants to have a certain value.

My Firebase structure:

[image]

Now, I only have the Child "Text" and the currendUser "0zwtyRwgnogC8Qk91AtHj7amZb63"

So how can I get the values of "text and "user_id"?

My source code:

```
 mDatabaseText = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Text");
    query = mDatabaseText.startAt(mCurrentUser.getUid());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot textSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                  /*  String text = textSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); */

                    TextModel textModel = chatSnapshot.getValue(TextModel.class);

                    String t = textModel.getText();
                    Log.i("!!!!!!!text", t);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But this code doesn't work, why?

I used the query `startAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference currentUserIdRef = rootRef.child("Text").child(currentUserId);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = (String) ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference userIdRef = rootRef.child("Text").child(currentUserId).child(userId);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String user_id = (String) dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                }
            };
            userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
};
currentUserIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `currentUserId` is the variable that you say you already have it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: mDatabaseText = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Text");
        query = mDatabaseText.orderByKey().startAt(mCurrentUser.getUid()).endAt(mCurrentUser.getUid() + "\uf8ff");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        final String key = chatSnapshot.getKey(); }}}}

Comment: What is this? I do not understand you.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Cheers!